# VBA - call Python script

Tags: python, vba, spyder

I have read several threads and found that I can call Python from VBA using Shell.

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Ret_Val = Shell("C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\...\REL.py", vbNormalFocus)

    If Ret_Val <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "ok!", vbOKOnly
    End If

End Sub
```

I do get the OK message, and a window open and close within a second. So my guess it is launching Python but the script does not work.

So I thought that maybe does not work because I wrote the code in spyder and I might need to launch spyder:

```
Ret_Val = Shell("C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder.exe C:\Users\...\REL.py", vbNormalFocus)
```

This will open Spyder, which takes too much time and it is not what I want. Also once it is opened, it does not launch the script.

Something is wrong, but I am not sure if it is due to the VBA code or something else related to the script. The script works when I run it from Spyder without VBA.

This is a simple example of the Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Apr 21 08:24:05 2017

@author: xxxxxx
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

RW = pd.read_excel('Raw_data.xlsx', skipinitialspace=True) 
RW=pd.DataFrame(RW, columns = ['Task Id', 'TIDmodRW', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Machine', 'Boards'])

writerRW = pd.ExcelWriter('RW_test2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
RW.to_excel(writerRW, sheet_name='sheet1')
writerRW.save()
```

Comment: Why don't you give a sample Python script to make this a [mcve]?

Comment: I added it in the question. I cut it to keep it simple, but it does not write the excel. The code works with Spyder

Comment: Perhaps you can add some error handling to the Python script, where the error handler prints the exception and has an `input("Press any key to close")` so that you can view the result before the window closes. By judicious use of `print()`, can you identify the line in the Python code which is throwing the error?

Comment: When using shell to pass file paths as arguments it's usually good practise to put the path(s) in quotes, in case they contain spaces.., - `Shell("C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\python.exe ""C:\Users\...\REL.py"" ", vbNormalFocus)`  Double-up the quotes to escape them as shown.

Comment: ...also make sure that *within your python script* the paths you're using are sufficient - not sure what python defaults to when only given a filename and not a full path: if it's the "current directory" then that might be different running from VBA vs. running directly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073553/open-function-python-default-directory

Comment: Excellent! It works now and I was able to see what was the error. Spyder was running from its directory and found the excel input file. While now it does not find it anymore. I will try to find an easy way to update the directory without specify the path in each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the built-in `os` module's `path.dirname()` to automatically detect the current path of your python script to locate the input Excel file (assuming the workbook is in same directory as .py script). Then, use the OS-agnostic `path.join()` to concatenate every file string with it for full directory reference. This method does not require backslashes (i.e., Windows) or forward slashes (i.e., Linux/Mac), so should work across operating systems.

So now, whatever folder the Excel file and Python file reside or whatever the call method including Spyder, VBA, or command line, the script should run fully reading and writing to local workbooks.

```
import os                                                # ADD IMPORT
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))          # LOCATE CURRENT DIR

# CONCATENATE CURRENT DIRECTORY TO EXCEL BASE FILE NAME
RW = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(cd, 'Raw_data.xlsx'), skipinitialspace=True) 
RW = pd.DataFrame(RW, columns = ['Task Id', 'TIDmodRW', 'Start Date', 
                                 'End Date', 'Machine', 'Boards'])

writerRW = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(cd, 'RW_test2.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
RW.to_excel(writerRW, sheet_name='sheet1')
writerRW.save()
```