# How to get a function to write to a text file?

Tags: python

I am writing a script that is a function that will take parameters in the command window and write them to a text file. I get no error messages, but the function won't actually write to a file. The purpose of my script is to write reminders to a text file, which will then be read by a different program.

The script is executed in the command window with python `C:\directory to file\write_list.py`.

I've previously include a `print(OUT)` which worked fine, but not in the text file. I've also tried doing the `file1` operations outside the function, but it did not work.

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.option("--c", default="R",help="Classification")
@click.option("--name", prompt="Name",
              help="Name of person/event")
@click.option("--date", prompt="Date of event", help="date of event")

def write_list(c, name, date):
    """writes parameters to text file"""
    file1 = open("ReminderList","a+")
    OUT=(c +":"+ name +"-" +date+"\n")
    file1.write(OUT)
    file1.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_list()
```

I expected to open the text file and see the parameters written.

Comment: Your function definition for `write_list()` says that you need 3 arguments - `c` , `name`, and `date`. But during the function call in `main`, you do not pass any arguments to `write_list()`.

Comment: In the command window i would include the arguments: such as python C:\Users\epett\eclipse-workspace\birthday_text\write_list.py --c=R --name=Bob --date=10/30

Comment: works for me. You probably aren't looking in the right place for the file you're writing.  add `import os
print("cwd: " + os.getcwd())` after `if __name__ ==  '__main__':` to see where you should be looking.

Comment: @RachayitaGiri the `click` library's decorators define a wrapped version of the function without the parameters

Comment: Yeah! I just checked. It works for me too. I believe you are right about where they should be looking for the output file.

Comment: Okay thank you! I just ran it in eclipse and it worked, however when I run it in the command window it doesn't, any thoughts?

Comment: You probably aren't looking in the right place for the file you're writing. `add import os print("cwd: " + os.getcwd())` after `if __name__ == '__main__':` to see where you should be looking. Did you check if you have permissions to write to that location?

Comment: I found the file and opened it and it writes to it just fine, just not from the windows command window. It works when I use eclipse console.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now, sorry I am a newbie, I am checking the permissions now

Comment: You can get the current directory is a script (which is where files will be written by default) via `cur_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)`. If you want to write a file to another directory use `file_path = os.join(desired_dir_path, 'my_name.txt')` to obtain an argument to pass to `open()`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Both ways worked, I found that it was just making two files with the same name in different places.

Comment: @martineau files are opened in `os.getcwd()` by default which can be different from `os.path.dirname(__file__)` [See here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11073553/1092820). e.g., if you're in `/home/foobar` and you run `$ python scripts/test.py`, then `os.path.dirname(__file__)` will be `"/home/foobar/scripts"` and files will open in `"/home/foobar"`, same as `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @Ruzihm: You're right. I should have saud "...get the directory of the script that's currently running".